# Fastest way to build matrix with concentric "rings" of values

Tags: performance, matlab, matrix

Say I have a vector `Q = [Q1 Q2 .... QN]`.

I would like to create a matrix A such that the kth "ring" of the matrix is equal to Qk, with the following constraint:

if `N` is odd, the central patch is composed of one number, which is `QN`

For `Q = [12 3 27]` this would be :

```
 A =

12    12    12    12    12
12     3     3     3    12
12     3    27     3    12
12     3     3     3    12
12    12    12    12    12
```

if `N` is even, the central patch is a 2x2 patch where `QN` gets repeated

for `Q = [12 3]` this would be

```
A =

12    12    12    12    
12     3     3    12 
12     3     3    12  
12    12    12    12
```

**Two for loops**

Two for loops work but it is too slow (~13,3s for 5000x5000 matrices) (Code below) :

```
%% Two for loops :

% Generate random integer vector Q with unique values
N = 5;
n = 15 * N;
Q = randperm(n,N).';

% Double for loop method


if mod(N,2)==1
    
    mSize = 2*N-1;
    
else
    
    mSize = 2*N;
    
end

A = zeros(mSize);

for ii=1:(mSize)
    
    for jj=1:(mSize)
        
        IDX = min([ii,jj,mSize-ii+1,mSize-jj+1]);
        
        A(ii,jj) = Q(IDX);
        
    end
    
end
```

**Faster approach**

I have found a faster approach, which is pretty good (~1.46s for 5000x5000 matrices) but there might still be some room for improvement :

```
if mod(N,2)==1

    mSize = 2*N-1;
    
    I_idx = (1:mSize)-N;
    
    A_fast = Q(end-max(abs(I_idx.'),abs(I_idx)));

else
    
    I_idx = [(N-1):-1:0 0:(N-1)];
    
    A_fast = Q(end-max(I_idx.',I_idx));
    
end
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't think you're likely to beat a single indexing operation for speed, although with the 4-way symmetry in that matrix, perhaps the downstream use for `A` could be improved by leveraging that - meaning you only need to generate one quadrant of `A`?

Comment: You could make a quarter of the matrix by repeating your vector N times (making a square) then taking just the upper or lower diagonal half of it and adding to the transpose (then sort out the diagonal by replacing with `diag(Q)`). It then just remains to mirror this for the other 4 quarters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The logic of the code is lightly simpler if you follow the advice [in Wolfie's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72378191/fastest-way-to-build-matrix-with-concentric-rings-of-values?noredirect=1#comment127865286_72378191), and compute only one quadrant that you repeat:

```matlab
I_idx = 1:N;
B = Q(min(I_idx,I_idx.'));
if mod(N,2)==1
    B = [B,B(:,end-1:-1:1)];  % same as [B,fliplr(B(:,1:end-1))]
    B = [B;B(end-1:-1:1,:)];  % same as [B;flipud(B(1:end-1,:))]
else
    B = [B,fliplr(B)];
    B = [B;flipud(B)];
end
```

This is 2-2.5 times as fast depending on whether `Q` is even or odd-sized.

[Steve's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72378191/fastest-way-to-build-matrix-with-concentric-rings-of-values?noredirect=1#comment127865810_72378191) suggest building a triangle first, but I don't see that being any faster, due to the complexity of indexing a matrix's upper or lower triangle.

---

Testing code:

```matlab
N = 5000;
n = 15 * N;
Q = randperm(n,N).';

tic
if mod(N,2)==1
    mSize = 2*N-1;
    I_idx = (1:mSize)-N;
    A = Q(end-max(abs(I_idx.'),abs(I_idx)));
else
    I_idx = [(N-1):-1:0 0:(N-1)];
    A = Q(end-max(I_idx.',I_idx));
end
toc

tic
I_idx = 1:N;
B = Q(min(I_idx,I_idx.'));
if mod(N,2)==1
    B = [B,B(:,end-1:-1:1)];
    B = [B;B(end-1:-1:1,:)];
else
    B = [B,fliplr(B)];
    B = [B;flipud(B)];
end
toc

isequal(A,B)
```

Answer (score 1):

I came up with a solution using repmat, then flipping along a diagonal to get a quarter of the solution, finally flipping and reversing twice to get the full output matrix.

```matlab
function A = flip_it_and_reverse_it(Q)
N = length(Q);
QQ = repmat(Q(:), 1, N);
quarter_A = triu(QQ) + triu(QQ, 1).';
half_A = [quarter_A, quarter_A(:, end-1:-1:1)];
A = [half_A; half_A(end-1:-1:1, :)];
end
```

There may be improvements that can be made to get faster flips/reverses with some clever transposes.

For the even case in your updated question, the indices in the lines starting `half_A` and `A` should be `end:-1:1` instead of `end-1:-1:1`.

Running some quick timings, it looks like my solution is comprable (sometimes slightly slower) to your faster approach:

```matlab
N = 5000;
n = 15 * N;
Q = randperm(n,N).';

disp('double loop')
tic
double_loop(Q);
disp(toc)

disp('faster approach')
tic
faster_approach(Q);
disp(toc)

disp('flip_it_and_reverse_it')
tic
flip_it_and_reverse_it(Q);
disp(toc)
```

Results:

```
double loop
   14.4767

faster approach
    1.8137

flip_it_and_reverse_it
    1.6556
```

Note: sometimes `faster_approach` wins, sometimes `flip` - I've got some other jobs running on my laptop.