# Ramping values of a matrix smoothly down to zero around its edges

Tags: matlab, matrix, memory, multidimensional-array, indexing

Hi I am looking for some help to optimize some Matlab code. I have an input matrix `M`, which is `Ny` rows by `Nx` columns. I would like to define a boundary all the way round the edge of the matrix where the values should be attenuated smoothly down to zero. To do this, I attempted to define a masking function `MSK` and multiply it point by point to get an output `N`, shown below:

[image]

[image]

My attempt above was created using the code below, where I use a cosine squared function to get the smooth drop off from 1 to zero:

```matlab
%%% Set up some grids %%%
Nx = 128;
Ny = 64;
dx = 0.1;
dy = 0.1;
x  = -(Nx*dx/2):dx:(Nx*dx/2-dx); 
y  = -(Ny*dy/2):dy:(Ny*dy/2-dy); 
x = permute(x, [1 2 3]); % Creates a [1 x Nx x 1] vector (saves memory)
y = permute(y, [2 1 3]); % Creates a [Ny x 1 x 1] vector

M = complex( double( rand(Ny,Nx)+10 ) ); % Create some input data

bnd_frac = 0.7; % The fraction of the grid to begin masking boundary, i.e 70% of the grid max

MSK = create_mask_function(x,y,Nx,Ny,bnd_frac);   % Create masking function

N = M.*MSK;  % Apply mask to input data, to smoothly ramp edges to zero

figure;
subplot(1,3,1);imagesc(x,y, abs(M) )
subplot(1,3,2);imagesc(x,y, abs(MSK) )
subplot(1,3,3);imagesc(x,y, abs(N) )

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% Masking Function %%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
function MSK = create_mask_function(x,y,Nx,Ny,bnd_frac)

[~,bndind_x] = min( abs(x - bnd_frac*x(Nx)) ); % Find the index to begin the masking
x_bound = x(bndind_x);                         % Find the grid coordinate to begin masking
[~,bndind_y] = min( abs(y - bnd_frac*y(Ny)) );
y_bound = y(bndind_y);

dbnd_xp = x(Nx) - x_bound; % Find the width of the boundary region at each edge
dbnd_xm = x(1)  + x_bound;
dbnd_yp = y(Ny) - y_bound;
dbnd_ym = y(1)  + y_bound;

MSK = ones(Ny,Nx); % Initialise the mask matrix as ones

% Set the values within each boundary region at the edge to ramp smoothly to 0 from 1
MSK( : , x >  x_bound ) = repmat( ( cos( ( x(x>+x_bound) - x_bound )/dbnd_xp * pi/2 ) ).^2 , Ny , 1);
MSK( : , x < -x_bound ) = repmat( ( cos( ( x(x<-x_bound) + x_bound )/dbnd_xm * pi/2 ) ).^2 , Ny , 1);
MSK( y >  y_bound , : ) = repmat( ( cos( ( y(y>+y_bound) - y_bound )/dbnd_yp * pi/2 ) ).^2 , 1 , Nx);
MSK( y < -y_bound , : ) = repmat( ( cos( ( y(y<-y_bound) + y_bound )/dbnd_ym * pi/2 ) ).^2 , 1 , Nx);

MSK(:,Nx,:) = 0;
MSK(:,1,:)  = 0;
MSK(Ny,:,:) = 0;
MSK(1,:,:)  = 0;

end
```

The problem with the code above is that it allocates too much memory to `MSK`.

(In the real version of my code, all of of the matrices are 3D, and the sizes can be more like 1024x512x512 in reality, but I have made a simplifed 2D example here to help explain.)

Note that this is the reason that I am using `permute()` on the `x` and `y` vectors above, because other parts of my full code use Matlab's [implicit expansion](https://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2019/12/19/importance-of-implicit-expansion-for-performance/). This is to avoid storing 3D versions of x and y that have been generated using `meshgrid()`.

It is clear in the above image that `MSK` contains mostly values of 1, and the ramping values only occur near the edges. So this seems like large waste of memory to store those 1's because their purpose is to just make sure the input matrix is not modified in the centre. Can anyone help me understand a way in Matlab to implement what I want but in a way that will use less RAM?

Comment: Can't you use a [separable](https://calculus.subwiki.org/wiki/Multiplicatively_separable_function) mask? That way you store one vector (and use twice) instead of one matrix

Comment: For example, let `in = magic(8);`. Instead of `MSK = [0 .5 1 1 1 1 .5 0].*[0 .5 1 1 1 1 .5 0].'; out = in.*MSK;` you could use `m = [0 .5 1 1 1 1 .5 0]; out = in.*m.*m.';`

Comment: Do you really want your mask to have the horizontal bands at the limits between the vertical and horizontal parts of the mask? You could work your way down the center with rings of ascending values, which is a lot easier to do

Comment: I hate citing myself, but here is a post that might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72378191/fastest-way-to-build-matrix-with-concentric-rings-of-values

Comment: @BillBokeey You are right, I don't want the bands where the two parts meets (ideally it would go smoothly round the corner). The approach given by Luis above actually seems to eliminate the bands. For the post you cited, I'm not sure if it solves the problem. In that post, you needed to finally store the entire "A_fast" matrix. In my case, this would be the MSK masking matrix, which I then need to multiply with my data matrix. The issue is how to avoid storing A_fast in RAM. Having said that, you approach might work - if you can post an example I'd be happy to accept it.

Comment: Yes, your problem is not equivalent. But you could use the indexing idea to build your output directly without building the mask :)

Answer (score 1):

If you can't store, then you need to recompute the weights each time and use them on the fly.

The short answer then is that instead of some precomputing of `MSK` and then usage later, as:

```
MSK( : , x >  x_bound ) = repmat( ( cos( ( x(x>+x_bound) - x_bound )/dbnd_xp * pi/2 ) ).^2 , Ny , 1);
etc()
...
 
N = M.*MSK
```

You want to just, on the fly:

```
N( : , x >  x_bound ) = M( : , x >  x_bound ).*repmat( ( cos( ( x(x>+x_bound) - x_bound )/dbnd_xp * pi/2 ) ).^2 , Ny , 1);
etc()
```

I'll leave how you restructure the code to you, but I'd basically just add the matrix `M` as input to your function, and rename it to "apply_mask" or something like that. There will likely be ways to optimize this further if needed, but "early optimization is the root of all evil".

Comment: Thanks, I see what you are saying. I think it's not that I "can't store", it's just that I can't store *everything* in MSK. Although I cannot store all the "1's" as well, I have enough free RAM to store the important bits at the edges where the ramp happens. In principle, this data should be represented as x2 small vectors (one for each of the edge ramps in the x and y directions).

Comment: @teeeeee fair, but the approach is the same. Just instead of storing the data in MSK, apply the filter at computing time. I wasn't trying to give you functioning code, just ilustrate the idea. You can always optimize it further.

Comment: The issue with your approach is that the mask must be recalculated each time. This multiplication applying the mask is actually part of a code which iterates many thousands of times (with the mask being applied each time), BUT the mask variable only changes every 100 or so iterations. So it does not need to be calculated each iteration. (I know I didn't mention this in the OP). The method in the comment from Luis seems to do the trick - but thank you for your answer.

Comment: @teeeeee great, hopefully he answers. But yeah, in general, saving on memory means costing in computation. I guess not this case.